# Raspberry Pi Opencv-3.2.0 facedetect C++ sample can't find Raspberry Pi camera

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, raspberry-pi3

-I have a 'Raspberry Pi 3'.

-Opereting System is 'RASPBIAN JESSIE WITH PIXEL'.

-My camera is 'Raspberry Pi Camera Module V2'.

This is Python Code which is works perfectly for Raspberry Pi camera:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()

camera.start_preview()
time.sleep(10)
camera.stop_preview()
```

So Raspberry Pi camera is working.

### Opencv-3.2.0 facedetect C++ sample:

Source Code:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/facedetect.cpp

For Compile:

> sudo g++ -o facedetect facedetect.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`

For "./facedetect" Output is:

> Capture from camera #0 didn't work
>
> Detecting face(s) in

For "./facedetect 1" Output is:

> Capture from camera #1 didn't work
>
> Detecting face(s) in 1

So facedetect C++ sample can't find Raspberry Pi camera. How can I fix this?

Comment: This doesn't have to do that much with just `facedetect` but with OpenCV and the Pi camera. You can't just access the Pi camera and tell OpenCV to use it. There are a bunch of tutorials out there which offer various solutions for this omho pretty annoying issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

Load the video for linux drivers as shown above

Answer (score -1):

For example

> OpenCV expects to talk to a V4L device

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60583/how-can-i-get-the-raspberry-pi-camera-working-with-c-on-opencv-3-2